# Optimizing Lucid/Solr to index large text documents

Tags: memory, solr, indexing

I am trying to index about 3 million text documents in solr.  About 1/3 of these files are emails that have about 1-5 paragraphs of text in them.  The remaining 2/3 files only have a few words to sentences each.

It takes Lucid/Solr nearly 1 hour to fully index the entire dataset I'm working with.  I'm trying to find ways to optimize this.  I have setup Lucid/Solr to only commit every 100,000 files, and it indexes the files in batches of 50,000 files at once.  Memory isn't an issue anymore, as it consistently stays around 1GB of memory because of the batching.

The entire dataset has to be indexed initially.  It's like a legacy system that has to be loaded to a new system, so the data has to be indexed and it needs to be as fast as possible, but I'm not sure what areas to look into to optimize this time.

I'm thinking that maybe there's a lot of little words like "the, a, because, should, if, ..." that are causing a lot of overhead and are just "noise" words.  I am curious if I cut them out if it would drastically speed up the indexing time.  I have been looking at the Lucid docs for a while, but I can't seem to find a way to specify what words not to index.  I came across the term "stop list" but didn't see much more than a reference to it in passing.

Are there other ways to make this indexing go faster or am I just stuck with a 1 hour indexing time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems from your query that Indexing time is really important for your application. Solr is a great search engine however if you need super fast indexing time and if that is a very important criteria for you, than you should go with Sphinx Search Engine. It wont take much of time for you to quickly setup and benchmark your results using Sphinx.

There can be ways (like the one you have mentioned, stopwords etc.) to optimize however whatever you do with respect to indexing time Solr won't be able to beat Sphinx. I have done benchmarking myself.

I too love Solr a lot because of its ease of use, its out of box great features like N-Gram Indexing, Faceting, Multi-core, Spelling Correctors and its integration with other apache products etc.. but when it comes to Optimized Algorithms (be it Index size, Index time etc.) Sphinx rocks!!

Sphinx too is open source. Try that out.

Comment: thanks for the reply.  Do you happen to have any numbers for your benchmarking that compares solr index times to sphinx index times?  Wondering if it's really worth my time to investigate speeding up the index times.  While index times are important to my app, I have to use solr for other reasons.

Answer (score 1):

We met similar problem recently. We can't use solrj as the request and response have to go through some applications, so we take the following steps: 
[Creating Custom Solr Type to Stream Large Text Field](http://lifelongprogrammer.blogspot.com/2013/11/creating-custom-solr-type-to-stream-Large-text-field.html)!

1. Use GZipOutput/InputStream and Bse64Output/InputStream to compress the large text. This can reduce size of text about 85%, this can reduce the time to transfer the request/response.
2. To reduce memory usage at client side:

   2.1 We use stream api(GSon stream or XML Stax) to read doc one by one.

   2.2 Define a custom Solr Field Type: FileTextField which accepts FileHolder as value. FileTextField will eventually pass a reader to Lucene. Lucene will use the reader to read content and add to index.

   2.3 When the text field is too big, first uncompress it to a temp file, create a FileHolder instance, then set the FileHolder instance as field value.